# Wine err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection, "?" wait timed out in thread

Tags: wine

While using certain types of installer on wine it often says:

```
009a:err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x22f488 "?" wait timed out in thread 009a, blocked by 008f, retrying (60 sec)
```

Or this

```
004b:err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x22f488 "?" wait timed out in thread 004b, blocked by 0043, retrying (60 sec)
```

And then is stuck in this loop for quite long time. Sometimes days, other times it finishes as quick as 10 minutes.
I am guessing this is an os-wine compatibility issue.

When run,it shows this

```
0057:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
ldmf mode
 ldmf memory per thread = 884'736kb
thread  0:  ldmf mem usage = 0kb + 2'280kb + tmp file 0kb
0057:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x22fac0 (nil)): stub
```

My system specs:
Kubuntu 20.04, Wine 5.0, i7 intel processor, NVidia 2060 rtx 6gb, 16 gb ddr ram.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Find your app at https://appdb.winehq.org and check for bug reports or howtos. If you find nothing, file a bug report https://bugs.winehq.org Remember that Wine is a reverse-engineered Win32 implementation, so you cannot expect everything to work.

Wine 5.0 is relatively old, you may want to try to reproduce the issue with Wine 5.20.